# Best sql architecture for self-join used in EF

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, entity-framework, database-design

I've got an architechural question regarding a self-join.

I have a table of objects with an unique int identifier. The objects can exist in isolation or as part of a collection of objects. The collection is represented as an object in the same table but with it's type set as collection.

e.g

```
1 | ObjectName | IsolatedObject
2 | CollectionName1 | CollectionObject
3 | CollectionName2 | CollectionObject
```

The object previously could belong to 0 or more collections, therefore I had another table that stored the mappings

e.g.

```
2 | 1
3 | 1
```

The decision has been made that they now can only belong to 1 collection. My question is whether it is better to keep the existing extra table or alter the table of objects to have a ParentID field which stores the unique ID?

This is also use with EF therefore the relationship mapping can become complicated.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general enforcing the integrity constraints in the application layer (aka leaving the data structure as-is) will not cause you problems immediately, but are likely to in the long run.  Leaving the data structure as-is might be a good intermediate solution until all of the data can be modified by end users to fit the new policy/requirement, but we have a saying in my office that 'if data can be put in there, it will be put in there'; meaning that if the referential integrity allows it you can bet it will happen.

My advice would be to get to the ParentID/Self-referencing model as fast as you can if that is the solution that truly models the requirement; of course this must be balanced with budget, time, user commitment, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Your mapping table is a good "extensible" solution if there are multiple groupings in the tree but it is overkill if there is only one grouping "level".
IE: If an Object Collection can have a master and NOT be a master for anything else then by all means do a self join.
However if the Object Collection can also be a master, your current mapping solution is better.

The reason for this is "do you need to walk the tree?"
To return all the relationships in SQL you will need to requery the table for each and every level (recursive).
If only Isolated Objects can be Master then a single query can return all values